# Modifications to a reg-ex compilation

Tags: php, regex, class, names

I have the following Regex used to match PHP Class, method and Function names to validate them, it was originally taken from PHP's site (Linked Below)

The problem is that it does not match single character classes, for example:

```
class a{}
class b{}
class A{}
class B{}
```

The regex is:

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

Now im not super at Regular Expressions as I choose not to use them if I can help it, but on this occasion I chose to use them.

I need to make 2 basic modifications to the regex:

- Allow single character's
- Cannot start with __ *(But can start with a single underscore followed by a letter)*

are there any Regular Expression guru's who can help me.

Regards

Comment: "The problem is that it does not match single character classes" --- the regex you've posted **does match** single character classes. http://ideone.com/m5iYR

Comment: oooh, my bad, in my code I have omitted the multiplier for some unknown reason, one of those moments. Thanks that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the possible answer:

Single char class:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~^(_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff])[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$~', 'a')); // 1
```

single underscore class:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~^(_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff])[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$~', '_')); // 1
```

double underscore class:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~^(_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff])[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$~', '__a')); //0
```

Comment: @K6t: just a delimiter. You can use any one you like: `!`, `#`, `/`, etc

Comment: sorry to ask! can u explain more about this syntax each character opertion ... or else can u give me Link..... I know basics...

Comment: `(_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff])` i think means `(_` single underscore `(?!_)` look ahead and make sure there is no second underscore `|` or a single char grouped, followed by any chars within the `[....]`